# Animate: surprise over discrete lists

Tags: animation

Consider `Animate[xs, {xs, {0, 1, 2}}]`. By my reading of [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html),

```
Animate[expr,{u,{u1,u2,…}}]
makes u take on discrete values u1, u2, ….
```

my expression should produce an animation that steps from `0` to `1` to `2` and back to `0` in a loop, and, indeed it does:

[image]

Now, consider `Animate[xs, {xs, {{"A", 0}, {"B", 1}, {"C", 2}}}]`. I would expect `xs` to take on the values `{"A", 0}`, `{"B", 1}`, and `{"C", 2}` in a loop, just as `xs` took on the values `0`, `1`, and `2` in a loop. I do not get what I expect. Instead, the display shows only `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` and the slider has a small excursion from 0 to 1 and a large excursion from 1 to 2:

[image]

Guessing that the second argument in each list tells Animate how long, relatively, to dwell on each frame, if I turn things around, `Animate[xs, {xs, {0, "A"}, {1, "B"}, {2, "C"}}]`, I get a frozen animator, though with no error message.

Under that hypothesis, I get what I want as follows

[image]

or, without the hypothesis, sort-of like this:

[image]

Did I miss something in the documentation? Did I misunderstand the documentation? Did I stumble on undocumented (albeit useful) behavior?

Comment: nice find! (+++1)